# Hide Elements in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Hope you're doing very well. I'm using `Tkinter designer` and Tkinter for the GUI of a program. But I have spent a whole day on a single problem, how to hide text on Canvas? I have tried many ways and this one is only the one that is acceptable.

```py
canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)


subtext = canvas.create_text(
    343.0,
    179.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="What made you here?",
    fill="#000000",
    font=("Roboto Condensed", 89 * -1),

)

subtext = Text

def Jokes():
    joke = random.choice(jokes)
    print(joke)
    subtext.pack_forget(self=subtext)
```

But this also throws an error **type object 'Text' has no attribute 'tk'** Please help, sorry for bad English and Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do on the line `subtext = Text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide a text item in a canvas, use `Canvas.itemconfigure(tagOrId, state='hidden')`:

```py
subtext = canvas.create_text(
    343.0,
    179.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="What made you here?",
    fill="#000000",
    font=("Roboto Condensed", 89 * -1),

)

# below line overwrite subtext
# it should not be called
#subtext = Text

def Jokes():
    joke = random.choice(jokes)
    print(joke)
    # hide the text item
    canvas.itemconfigure(subtext, state='hidden')
```

Comment: Yay! This works  But how to enable it again?

Comment: `canvas.itemconfigure(subtext, state='normal')`.